# How to call a method when the Done Button in the KeyBoard is Clicked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I want to call a method when the done button is clicked in the UITextField KeyBoard? Please Help me...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not even necessary to implement the delegate.  I greatly prefer using good, old-fashioned target/action pattern to handle this.  It can also lead to cleaner code if you have multiple ways of ending editing (say, intercepting touches outside the text field to cancel editing).

To use target/action, simply wire up `UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit`, which shows up in Interface Builder as the `Did End On Exit` event.

No muss, no fuss.  A lot cleaner and easier than implementing the delegate.

Answer (score 6):

See the [UITextFieldDelegate Protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol). You probably want to implement the `– textFieldShouldReturn:` method in your delegate.

Comment: -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;

Comment: @drawnonward - right, textFieldShouldReturn: is a better fit for what he's asking than textFieldDidEndEditing:; I'll edit that in.