# how do I know when UIKeyboard Join button is tapped?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

How do I know when a user taps on the Join button on the UIKeyboard?

Also can this text be changed?  I know there are several built options but I nee done that says 'Login' if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of using `UITextField` delegate just for knowing when keyboard entry is completed by pressing the "return" on the keyboard (whatever it's labeled). UITextField actually works well with a Target/Action pattern which is much simpler and far more direct than using the delegate for this.

I've pointed this out before in an answer to "[How to call a method when the Done Button in the KeyBoard is Clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650513/how-to-call-a-method-when-the-done-button-in-the-keyboard-is-clicked/2651023#2651023)". Please take a look at that for the details of using the traditional target/action pattern to know when keyboard entry is complete. Unfortunately, Apple's documentation isn't as clear is it could be on this subject.

`UITextField` delegate has its place, but if all you need is to know when entry is complete then using the delegate likely isn't the best approach. Use target/action.

For the UIReturnKeyType choices, see the `returnKeyType` property in the [UITextInputTraits Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIReturnKeyType).

Answer (score 0):

You should set your delegate of your `UITextField` (I'm assuming that's a `UITextField`) and check for that delegate call :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

Also, you return a `BOOL` to tell the `UITextField` to do its default behavior or not. You can check the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate).

Also, the options Apple gives you for the `UIReturnKeyType` are your only options.