# UITextField method call when done button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a textfield in a `UITableViewCell`

When I clicked in textfield directly this method is called:

```
-(void)editingChanged:(UITextField *)sender
```

this is my code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[cell.ProductQuantityTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingChanged:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


-(void) editingChanged:(UITextField *)sender
{
    NSLog( @"text changed: %@",cell.ProductQuantityTextField.text);
    [self ProdcutDirectSetToCartAPICall];
}
```

I want that, when I click the textfield then I change the value of textfield and then I click done button of keyboard that time I want call `UITextField` method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method when the Done Button in the KeyBoard is Clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650513/how-to-call-a-method-when-the-done-button-in-the-keyboard-is-clicked)

Comment: thanks its very useful..

Comment: @Odedra your problem solved or not?

Comment: yes its solved but UITextField delegate method is not called for first time after that it call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check UItextfield's shouldreturn method call

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog( @"text changed: %@",textField.text);
    [self ProdcutDirectSetToCartAPICall];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the `shouldReturn` delegate method is what you are looking for:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    // do something
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thanks i already used this method but i cant get value from cell.ProductQuantityTextField.text !

Comment: you get the textfield as an argument. so try  `NSLog(@"%@", textField.text)` within the delegate method to get the text.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a two way to do that**

1.) Either you can perform UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit event.

2.) Or you can also implement your method in text field retun

```
<UITextfieldDelegate> //in yourController.h file

//yourController.m
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
 {

 //do your code here.     

return YES;
}
```

**Both method will help you to resolve your problem.**

Answer (score 0):

I think `forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged` is called every time when you change some contents inside the `UITextField`. If you want to call that method when user clicks `'Done'` button on your keyboard then try changing the line

```
[cell.ProductQuantityTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingChanged:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

with

```
[cell.ProductQuantityTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingChanged:)UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
```

Answer (score 0):

implement the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol in your class, set

```
ProductQuantityTextField.delegate = self;
```

and use

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"Textfield text %@", textField.text);
   [self ProdcutDirectSetToCartAPICall];
}
```

or

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked below code its working fine

In cellForRowAtIndexPath I added below code

```
 cell.ProductQuantityTextField.delegate = self;

 cell.ProductQuantityTextField.tag = indexPath.row; //If you want you can give tag here

 [cell.ProductQuantityTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


-(void)editingChanged:(UITextField *)field
{

    NSLog( @"text changed: %@",field.text);

}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {


    NSLog( @"textFieldShouldReturn: %@",textField.text);

   [textField resignFirstResponder];

   //If you need cell
    TableViewCellName *cell = (TableViewCellName*) [[textField superview]superview];

    NSLog( @"text changed: %@",cell.ProductQuantityTextField.text);

   [self ProdcutDirectSetToCartAPICall];

   return YES;
}
```

Comment: ProductQuantityTextField *cell = (ProductQuantityTextField*) [[textField superview] superview];
this error: Use of undeclared identifier 'ProductQuantityTextField

Comment: Sorry you can take as uitableview cell type